# Format all occurences of 0 to 0.00 (using C# regular expression)

Tags: c#, regex

I have some comma delimited data as follows:

```
John, Dog, 0, 00, 0, 0.00, 123
```

and I would like the 0 to be have 2 decimal places.. 
The output should be:

```
John, Dog, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 123
```

Is there a way to do this ?

I have deliberately left random spaces before/afer some commas.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use regular expressions?  Would you be willing to accept and answer that does not use regex?  If so, I would recommend not proposing a solution while asking the question.

Comment: Oh, I'm quite unfamiliar with these expressions. I tried something like [^\w],*([0]*[0](,*|\s)+)

Comment: A solution using regular expressions would be preferred.

Comment: If you are not familiar with regular expressions, why do you want to use them?

Comment: What's the problem with Regex here? We see so many questions "How to do X with Y" where Y = RegEx|Linq|SQL|...  And I would use a regex for this problem too.

Comment: Regex is overkill when `String.Replace()` can do the job.

Comment: Is it because of System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations validation that you need regex, because than you could look into CustomValidation and could use the better readable for loops in one of the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In response to my comment.  This is a trivial problem to solve without using regex.

```
string input = "John, Dog, 0, 00, 0, 0.00, 123";
string[] items = input.Split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    string value = items[i].Trim();
    int converted;

    if (int.TryParse(value, out converted))
    {
        if (converted == 0)
        {
            items[i].Replace(value, "0.00");
        }
    }        
}

string output = string.Join(items, ",");
```

Comment: And not using regular expressions gives you the benefit of understand the code the next time you have to look at it.

Comment: This is nice though I need a reg expression.

Comment: Why do you **need** a regular expression?

Comment: This doesn't even compile. There's no such thing as a static `string.Split`, the `i` isn't declared, and there's no variable called `item`.

Comment: @Porges Sorry, Firefox doesn't make a good IDE.  I've corrected these mistakes.

Comment: `string.Join` has its arguments reversed, and `input.Split` should take a character argument. Also, this approach doesn't handle "0.0" correctly.

Comment: @cadrell0 gave you the vote back I took. I think every question for a Regex should eventually ever be **Learn the way a regular expression works** because not knowing how it works keeps everyone copying and pasting regexes forever.

Comment: @Porges **Disclaimer** this answer is not meant to represent a fully functional and tested code snippet that can be directly pasted into a project.  It is meant to show the logic required to perform a given task.  As such it may contain errors and typos.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another trivial solution that doesn't use regex.

```
string input = "John, Dog, 0, 00, 0, 0.00, 123";
string[] items = input.Split(",");

for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++)
{
    int intValue;
    if (Int32.TryParse(items[i].Trim(), out intValue))
    {
        if (intValue == 0)
            items[i] = intValue.ToString("f2");
    }
}

string output = string.Join(items, ", ");
```

Comment: This would not catch the 00 as I stated at @cadrell0.

Comment: There's no such thing as a static `string.Split`, `i` isn't declared, and the arguments to `string.Join` are reversed. Also, this doesn't handle "0.0".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that should handle basically everything you can throw at it:

```
Regex.Replace("John, Dog0, D0g, 0Dog, 10, 10.0, 00, 0, 0.00, 0.0, 0.000, 00.00, 123",
         @"(?<=,\s*|^)0+(\.0*)?(?=\s*,|$)", "0.00")
```

Output:

```
John, Dog0, D0g, 0Dog, 10, 10.0, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 0.00, 123
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
(?<=,\s*|^) # after either a comma or the start of a string
0+          # match at least one '0'
(\.0*)?     # match an optional fractional part
(?=\s*,|$)  # must be before a comma of the end of the string
```

Comment: Hi Porges, that looks like it should be perfect. Though I couldnt get the string to select any zeros (?<=,\s*|^)0+(\.0*)?(?=\s*,|$) , MAybe I had some spurious space..not sure

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the trick in quick testing:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

Regex regex = new Regex( "\\b(?:0|\\.)+\\b" );

string input = "John, Dog,0, 00,000.0000, 0, 0.00, 123, 007,0";
string result = regex.Replace( input, "0.00");
```

We just look for any consecutive string of zeroes and periods on word boundaries, and replace with "0.00". As such, it will fall for invalid data such as "0.0...000", but maybe that is acceptable.